# Mysql syntax help -- Update

Tags: mysql

I have 1500 rows and i want to update all the rows with a constant value(Varchar)

This can done using UPDATE command in Mysql but i am not sure about the syntax for that..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could have done more research before posting this question, just by googling mySQL update or just SQL Update

Comment: [RTFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourField="yourValue"
```

If you want to update only some fields, not all, add a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourField="yourValue" WHERE id=1
```

You should consult the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) before asking basic syntax questions.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is :

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

So for your case it will be

```
 UPDATE table_name SET column1=value
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tblName SET variable='value';

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table_name
SET field_name='NEW_VALUE'
WHERE some_field = ''